Why doesn't my emacs use lsp-pyright?
I've desperately been trying to use the lsp-pyright server, but Emacs doesn't seem to recognize that it's installed...
What I did:
Configured it like described in the docs:
(use-package lsp-pyright
  :ensure t
  :custom (lsp-pyright-langserver-command "basedpyright") ;; or basedpyright
  :hook (python-mode . (lambda ()
                          (require 'lsp-pyright)
                          (lsp-deferred))))  ; or lsp-deferred

Install lsp server with lsp-install-server:
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/projects/TAMPON-Display/" -*-
Comint started at Fri Dec 27 13:22:46

/usr/bin/npm -g --prefix /home/markus/.emacs.d/.cache/lsp/npm/basedpyright install basedpyright

changed 1 package in 3s

Comint finished at Fri Dec 27 13:22:50

But whenever I want to start lsp-mode, I get this error:
LSP :: The following servers support current file but do not have automatic installation: semgrep-ls ruff pylsp pyls
You may find the installation instructions at https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/languages.
(If you have already installed the server check *lsp-log*).

lsp-pyright isn't even mentioned.  But oh yes, it is! in lsp-log:
Command "/home/markus/.emacs.d/.cache/lsp/npm/basedpyright/bin/basedpyright-langserver --stdio" is present on the path.

So Emacs knows it's available, but .. doesn't. I'm going crazy, please help...

basedpyright documentation suggest to install it with pypi, which is a wrapper to the npm package and is easy to be find out. Otherwise you may have path problems. The normal pyright if installed is recognized?

I would have thought that using the emacs native method (lsp-install-server) to install the language server should be the best way... Anyway, I tried other methods described in the docs. All worked to install the server but emacs recognized none of them.
Normal pyright did also not work.

I feel quite stupid now...But the reason why this didn't work is because I disabled pyright a long while ago:
'(lsp-disabled-clients '(pyright))

grep -lr .emacs.d pyright revealed it for me...
